# Positive part function of random variable

Tags: probability, asymptotics

$\{\boldsymbol{X}_i\}_{i = 1}^N$ is i.i.d. and nonnegative random variables with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$, and $a>0$ is a constant. How to bound the gap:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i = 1}^N(a-X_i)^+ \right] - \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i = 1}^N(a-X_i)\right]^+
\end{equation*}